# Swap arbitrary 3D Array Values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array:

```
array = [[[1,2],[4,5]],[[6,7],[8,9]]];
```

I would like to have the following result:

```
easyArray = [[[2,1],[5,4]],[[7,6],[9,8]]];
```

I tried

```
function swapCoordinates(array){
var a=0;
var b=0;
    for (j=0;j<array[0].length;j++){
        for (k=0;k<array[0][0].length;k++){
            var swap = array[a][b][0];
            array[a][b][0] = array[a][b][1];
            array[a][b][1] = swap
            console.log(a);
            a++;
            console.log(b);

        }
        console.log(a);
        console.log(b);
        b++

    }

return array;
}
```

The problem with it is, that I don't know how to increment b properly to get also e.g. array[1,0,0] ...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a recursive approach by checking if the item is an array with another array inside.

Then either map the arrays or return swapped items.

```js
var array = [[[1, 2], [4, 5]], [[6, 7], [8, 9]]],
    swapped = array.map(function swap(a) {
        return Array.isArray(a) && Array.isArray(a[0])
            ? a.map(swap)
            : a.slice().reverse();
    });
    
console.log(swapped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do as follows;

```js
var array  = [[[1,2],[4,5]],[[6,7],[8,9]]],
    swap3D = ([e0,e1,...es]) => e0 ? Array.isArray(e0) ? [swap3D(e0)].concat(swap3D([e1,...es]))
                                                       : [e1,e0]
                                   : [],
    result = JSON.stringify(swap3D(array));
console.log(result);
```